# What to check on HVAC after verifying blower motor works?

Tags: hvac, acura

I drive an 2003 Acura TL.  This week, the fan stopped blowing air, regardless of what setting the temperature / A/C is one.

I pulled out the blower motor and connected a multimeter to it.  The reading is 0 volts with the ignition set to off, 9.5 volts with the ignition set to on with the HVAC turned off, and about 11 volts with the HVAC turned on.

I took it to a shop this morning.  The mechanic there said that he does not know A/C well, but he tried connecting the blower motor directly to the car's 12V battery and it came to life.  I don't understand what could be going wrong here.

What should I check next?

Comment: Did you commect your meter to the harness connector or the motor? Did you check the ground side of the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

On BMWs when the blower motor goes off the reservation, it is usually the final stage/blower motor resistor. Does your car have one of those? If so, check it as it could be bad.